# Moved magento site to another host, redirecting to the old site

Tags: magento, redirect

We have moved out magento site to another host. But it is redirecting to the old site

We did following changes before moving the site

```
1. DB backup
2. files are zipped and copied to another host.
```

after moving the site to another host

```
1. changed the /web/secure and /web/unsecure values in the DB.
2. In magento files /app/etc/local.xml changed the database name.
3. cleared the var/cache
4. cleared the var/tmp
5. cleared the var/session.
```

but still the magento site is redirected to old site.

Can any one help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you updated the DNS to point the domain to the new server?

Comment: We've check with other folders, the server url works. DNS is not the issue - it has to do with Magento file system.

Comment: I have seen this before and it was down to browser cache.

Comment: Check your .htacces to ensure there are no rewrite rules and as Sulman said might be browser cache. Close it and re-open it completely rather than just clearing it, especially if Chrome. Ensure you have no host entries doing the redirect on your own machine. Otherwise I think you've covered everything that would cause this so maybe just re-check everything you said above. When you say redirect, are you defiantly getting a 301 or 302 redirect response?

Comment: @AshleySwatton How can we check 301 or 302 redirect?

Comment: Use a proxy application such as Charles to route your requests through so you can view the request headers. This will tell you if you are truly are being redirected from old server to new.

Comment: Browser cache often messes things up. Try using a different browser from a different machine to be even more sure.

Comment: Do you use compiled sources (includes/src)? Additionally search for the old domain as string in DB (db-wide search in phpmyadmin) and in all magento files (e.g. with MC). Maybe someone put a special redirect routine in it.

Answer (score 16):

### Several steps involved in cloning or moving a website.

**NOTE:** It's common practice to empty the var/cache, var/session directories before copying to new location. Clearing cache is mentioned below as it's necessary to clear the cached config after you've run through the list and properly set database access, BaseURL, etc.

1. Copy application files to new location and import database into MySQL. (best to do this with a tarball and database dump sql file, ftp has issues with things like getting .htaccess files to transfer, case to matter, etc.) Note: more sophisticated Magento admins use rsync, it's far easier.
2. **(important!!)** Make sure file/folder permissions and owner/group are correct so that `var/` folder system is writable. Otherwise the Magento cache gets written in system `/tmp` instead of Magento `var/` and only a server reboot or manual deletion will clear Magento cache out of `/tmp` . Also, not having var/ writable means that any drastic errors that write a file to `var/report/` will fail to write any stack traces, compounding your installation heartburn.
3. Make sure `app/etc/local.xml` points to the proper database and make sure if you back up the original `local.xml` that it doesn't end in `.xml` -> needs to be something like `local.xml.sv1`
4. Change your database entries Unsecure BaseUrl for and Secure BaseURL to point to your new location (`http://www.example.com` and if ssl cert installed `https://www.example.com` respectively). Use phpmyadmin to look for the paths `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` in the `core_config_data` table. (**Note:** entries will exist for each scope set, minimum is Global)
5. Manually clear your cache by deleting all the `mage--?` subfolders in `var/cache`
6. If you were using the compiler on the previous site, disable compiler with SSH command line `php shell/compiler.php disable` from the Magento root.
7. Attempt to load your admin backend, you should be on the new server URL now.

Following these steps should clear all the hiccups that cause Magento to adamantly redirect back to the old server. And believe me, I've had them all happen.

Comment: You should read first what the people already have tried. Should save you the effort.

Comment: I answered the question in full so everyone could have a checklist of things pertinent to the question at the top. There is one very important missing item they did not report that they did. So it might save someone else the effort.

Comment: After step 4 I get this error: "Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /var/lib/php/sessions)"  (I finished all the steps as well, but to no avail). Any tips?