# Moving Magento to new server checklist

Tags: sql-server, magento, installation

So I'm trying to manually move Magento to new server with old school ftp/phpmyadmin method. I only have the sql dump and folders from the root of old server, not access to it anymore and I don't know the earlier magento version number.

Should I

1. do fresh install of Magento to new server and then substitute folders and somehow import sql?

or

2. dump the files and sql to the new server first and then run the installer (something else?)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually below methods are followed,

1. Empty your cache admin sessions
2. Empty your logs (mysql)
3. create backup your database and your files
4. check your new server that supports magento using **[this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento)**
5. upload your files and import your db. If your database size is very large then directly import your database to your mysql server using sql command. Command would be like this,

   `mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql`
   for this you need to logged in your server(mysql)
6. Update your mysql credentials to your etc file and update path in `core_config_data` table .
7. Place some dummy orders to check emails are correctly delivered and payment, shipping etc.
8. Buy SSL Certificates and avoid shared hosting.

Comment: Ok perfect thanks so I don't run the install at all and just upload the files, sql and then hope for the best?

Comment: Make sure file/directory permissions are properly set before trying to bring up Magento for the first time. Also, BaseURLs need to be set to the new server. [Moved Magento to another host, redirecting back to the old site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178264/moved-magento-site-to-another-host-redirecting-to-the-old-site/26188706#26188706)