# Magento - How do i transfer from local to live`?

Tags: magento

I know this question has been ask quite a few times, but nothing seems to be working for me...
I really need help. I have made my entire website on my localhost, but hos do i get it up and running live? I've tried everything :( I've copied all of my files onto the live server and looked at endless tutorials, but nothings working. Can you maybe do a video about this or tell med what to do? I really don't want to start ALL OVER on creating all the pages and static blocks and so on.﻿

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving Magento to new server checklist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213468/moving-magento-to-new-server-checklist)

Answer (score 1):

You have to just change the url in database table. Run the query

```
 SELECT *
 FROM `core_config_data`
 WHERE `value` LIKE 'http://%';
```

and change the url from localhost to live server url. Hopefully that'll work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you already created many blocks, cms pages and did a lot customizations in backend in local system. You have to do next:

1. Copy your magento code completely to server.
2. On server, delete app/etc/local.xml
3. Create empty mysql database on the server
4. Backup your local database
5. Import that local database into database on server (which you created in step 3.)
6. Run magento site via browser

because you deleted local.xml file, magento will start installing process and ask you for params for db in server (here, enter data which you used for creation db in step 3, like db nambe, username, password,..). And that's it. Magento will make connection with that db and you will have everything you had in local.

One more thing which I forgot:

you have to change in database on field (you will change this on live database after importing local database, that means after step 5). There should be table core_config_data. Do search in that table, and wherever you find you local url like:

```
http://localhost/magento/
```

or something like that, you should change to your real domain, for example to:

```
http://my-magento-domain.com/
```