# Moving a magento webshop from local to live

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento

I have a problem with moving a magento webshop to a online server.

- I copied all the files to the server with filezilla, changed the local.xml file,
- I changed "localhost/magento" to "www.mysitename.com"
- I deleted the cache files in var/cache

Did i miss something?

Comment: Perhaps a configuration file contains an absolute path or forgotten credentials for db access to be updated? Not that I installed Magento recently but just thinking what could be wrong. Do you have a specific error that makes you think it is a problem? Or if you don't see any error then perhaps enable php to display some errors or check the server errors? Transferred files with filezilla, what about certain file permissions that might be required by Magento? Some questions, huh?

Comment: Not sure if you already figured it out but I read something about core_config_data table in the database beyond the config files: check it out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762090/how-do-i-transfer-a-local-magento-install-onto-my-live-server - if you didn't already. Hope these helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178264/moved-magento-site-to-another-host-redirecting-to-the-old-site/26188706#26188706

Answer (score 0):

Moving magento eCommerce website from one server to other

- Zip website folder on source server (local).
- Dump database
- Transfer zip file and database dump from source server to destination server
- Extract files to webroot folder on destination server
- Change permission of folders to 755 and files to 644 in the extracted folder if your server did not do at extraction with following command

  find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

  find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

Make sure you run these commands on magento root folder.

- Create database on destination server and import dumped database
- Edit local.xml file in webroot/app/etc folder and change database info
- Edit database table core_config_data and change unsecure and secure paths like bellow

  UPDATE TABLE core_config_data SET value = "{new url}" WHERE path = "web/unsecure/base_url";
  UPDATE TABLE core_config_data SET value = "{new url}" WHERE path = "web/secure/base_url";
- Empty **var/cache** , **var/session** , **var/log** , **var/report** folders in webroot folder
- May need to reindex your data: catalog url rewrites via admin panel > System > Index Management

Note: If you posted the error it would be easier to help!

Comment: I would like to post the error, but when i go to var/report i can't see the error..

Comment: So what do you see on your browser? Turn on error_reporting = E_ALL and display_errors = On too.

Comment: I can't find "error_reporting" in index.php, but i uncomment the following line: #ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: If Magento gives you the `There is an error processing your request` message but there is no file being written to `var/report` with that number for a file name, you have massive file system permissions problems.

Comment: You can set error_reporting on index.php like error_reporting (E_ALL). Find that line. And set $_SERVER ['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true. You may want to SetEnv  MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true" in .htaccess file. Have changed permissions?!